# Cache strategies, what reference article could I study?

Tags: reference-request, efficiency, cpu-cache

So as to optimize an application, I must implement data caching: not to recompute some data - those heavy on cpu but that don't change often.

When playing with the idea, I imagined something like the way win32/MFC manages the windows screen i.e.:

- While a part is valid, it is not repainted.
- When a rectangle or a region is invalidated, this part is repainted during the next painting session - launched by the OS.

I was imagining a way to validate and invalidate my cached value, so as to recompute only what is necessary when it is necessary.

Then I read [this wikipedia page about Cache Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms), and none of the listed algorithm was using the technique I explained above. So I feel ill at ease, and I need to read some work about caching.

Do you know of some resources that I could rely on before I start implementing my own cache process ?

Comment: Are you interested in something like a programming tutorial or best practice, or do you want sciencey answers?

Comment: @Raphael I have started to read the article that Reza's answer is pointing to. It's pretty much what I expected/wanted: Theoretical critiques and point of view over real life application of cache algorithms. However, if you have other ressources that you might find helpful, don't hesitate: I love having several learning and knowledge sources.

Comment: I don't have references handy; it's just that in the first case, your question would be offtopic here. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best strategy to find the best suitable algorithms for caching is to read survey papers in this area. I recommend the paper [A survey of Web cache replacement strategies](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=954341) by Podlipnig and Böszörmenyi (2003) which reviews many general techniques for caching.

Answer (score 2):

The best overall view on optimization I've seen is Bentley's "Writing efficient programs" (sadly out of print), the medular part of its rules are in his ["Programming pearls"](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/). For analysis of the algorithms I'd dig into Cormen et al "Introduction to Algorithms" (don't let the "introduction" fool you, it is more an encyclopaedia).

Comment: Aren't those a bit too general?

Comment: @Raphael, can't give a specific answer to a general question...

Comment: Well, the question is focused on caching (if very general otherwise), so general program optimisation references seem to be too general. YMMV.

Comment: It asked specifically on optimizing performance by caching... and that may well be the wrong strategy.